# show error line and file when compile coffeeify

Tags: browserify

How to make `browserify` show error line and file  on compile:

```
browserify  -t coffeeify mainPage_browserify.coffee > main.js -d
```

The current output don't give this information. So it is hard to debug:

```
                                                                                                                                ⏎
Error: Cannot find module 'throw' from '/allProjectsPath/project/public/javascripts/map'
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:50:17
  at process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:119:43)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:128:21
  at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:60:43)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:66:22
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:21:47
  at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)



❯ browserify --version                                                                                                                                                                                    ⏎
5.12.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was interested in this by myself, so I had a quick peek into source code and run debugger. It looks like that errors from transforms are basically swallowed when using command line browserify.

Errors from coffeeify are passed using event emitter on the stream...

https://github.com/substack/coffeeify/blob/master/index.js#L35

These are handled by Browserify only if the `bundle` call was made with callback present...

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/master/index.js#L619

Unfortunately callback is not passed when running the command line...

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/master/bin/cmd.js#L55

Comment: Actually nevermind this. You got me confused because error you are showing above is not about Coffeeify, it's about missing module. I don't want to dig this deep, but this type of errors simply means that you have `require` call for non existing module.